# What does SecurityInterstitialCommandId.CMD_PROCEED actually does?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I am working on some SSL Certificate errors, and found that is a website has SSL Error 
run `sendCommand(SecurityInterstitialCommandId.CMD_PROCEED)` 
in **Chrome** console and the site will be loaded.

When I load the site again no error or warning page is shown, Can someone tell me how this command works and how can I revert the untrusted site back to how it was (showing untrusted warning).

I think clearing the site data will revert, but I'm not sure if that's right, If its right is there a js command like the above one to clear site data of a particular website?

Tested site : `expired.badssl.com` & `wrong.host.badssl.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is from https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/f8d4f3dec98d8a9836847c256753a12cd3e809ce/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js#L23

If you want to revert the untrusted site page back, click the red `Not Secure` icon before the url in browser address bar, then click the red `Re-enable warnings`.